# Phrasal template detection

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

Is there an easy way to detect a phrasal template in a block of text?

For example, given the text:

> Not sure how to approach this. It's very difficult, and by difficult I mean I don't know how to do it. But maybe it's obvious for someone else?

And the template:

> [x], and by [x] I mean [Y]

Would result in a match.

I would assume that regex of some description would be the best bet, although I don't know if such a thing is possible with regex.

Bonus: what would be the most computationally efficient approach, if trying to match many templates in succession?

Edit: Just to clarify, I just need an exact match. For example the above template would *not* have to match the following:

> apple, and by apple I do mean pear

Comment: In order to find the *most common* phrasal templates in the text, I would do [collocation extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_extraction) to find frequent sequences of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need matching by regexp you can use this one:

```
(\w+), and by \1 I mean \w+

apple, and by apple I mean pineapple -> match
apple, and by apple I do mean pear -> not match

(\w+) - matches 1 word and save it to first group
\1 - word from first group
\w+ - match second word
```

Play with regexps more on http://regexpal.com/

But if you really need matching with lot of patterns you need define all patterns that you need and build own [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)